# Incomplete \iffalse in \caption, but correct in regular text. Where's the \if?

Tags: captions, phantom

I'm trying to create a new character as a superposition of `$\bot$` and `=`, as follows:

[image: Using the command <code>\disjointcompl</code> in regular environments]

For some reason it is not working in \caption environments, as opposed to regular environments. What is wrong; where is the conflicting \if -statement?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}    

% Disjoint & complete (\disjointcompl) character, as a superimpose of \bot and = .
\newcommand{\disjointcompl}{%
  \mathrel{
    \vphantom{=}\text{
      \mathsurround=0pt\ooalign{
        $\bot$\cr\raisebox{-0.89ex}{$=$}\cr
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
The disjoint \& complete context is denoted as $\disjointcompl$  

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A correspondence over a \emph{disjoint class context}. The current  context is defined as \( \disjointcompl  \)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code generates the following error:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 19.
<inserted text> 
                \fi
```

Wheras removing the `\disjointcompl` in the caption makes the code work and produces the picture above.

Comment: `\protect\disjointcompl`? Or define `\newcommand{\disjointcompl}` with `etoolbox`'s `\newrobustcmd`: `\newrobustcmd{\disjointcompl}`.

Comment: As moewe says, this is clearly a problem of a fragile command in a moving argument. `\protect\disjointcompl` solves it; or replace `\newcommand{\disjointcompl}` with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\disjointcompl}`

Comment: The symbol has three horizontal bars; I guess you only want two.

Comment: @egreg Indeed I want two bars; a matter of trial-and-error in positioning the \bot, which is dependent on the particular font *sigh*.

Comment: I'm afraid that the having a definition working with every font is a dream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your definition of `\disjointcompl` makes it a fragile command, that has to be prefixed by `\protect` if used in a moving argument (caption or section title).

You can use `\DeclareRobustCommand`, in order to avoid the issue.

Here's a modified definition of your command that works in captions and also exactly superimposes the top bar of the equal sign to the bar of `\bot`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}    

% Disjoint & complete (\disjointcompl) character, as a superimpose of \bot and = .
\DeclareRobustCommand{\disjointcompl}{%
  \mathrel{\text{%
    \mathsurround=0pt
    \vtop{\offinterlineskip
      \ialign{##\cr
        $\bot$\cr
        \noalign{\kern-0.1ex}
        $=$\cr
      }
    }%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}
The disjoint \& complete context is denoted as
$\disjointcompl_{\disjointcompl_{\disjointcompl}}$

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \caption{A correspondence over a \emph{disjoint class context}. The current  context is defined as \( \disjointcompl  \)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Very magnified version

[image]